# Getting error TF277003: Cannot add more than one upgrade process template for team project

Tags: tfs, upgrade, tfs-migration

I'm having troubles upgrading the TFS 2010 enviroument to a TFS 2012 enviroument. During the upgrade i am getting the follow error:

TF277003: Cannot add more than one upgrade process template for team project Tjip.QA.

I used the follow steps to get this error:

1. First I created a backup from our productional TFS 2010 enviroument, and copied it to a new data-tier server. After that I imported the backup, and tables "Tfs_Configuration", "Tfs_DefaultCollection", "Tfs_Warehouse" and an other database for a secundairy project collection.
2. I created a SQL backup from our productional TFS Reporting Server, and restored that backup to a new reporting server (with its encryption key).
3. I ran the TFS upgrade wizard on a new TFS application-tier server. After a lot of hours waiting, I am getting the above error.
   When I look in the database I see that the project only has one build-template; and its type is set to "2".

I hope that there is someone who can help me with this question.

Thnx,
Jeroen Niesen

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked and answered on: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsgeneral/thread/5b3cc988-778e-4bfd-93c1-79eadd5b1747

**Please note that you should never edit the TFS databases directly as it can leave your system in an unstable state and *will* make your system unsupportable by Microsoft except by best effort.**

I would burn a premium support call for this! You get 4 with each of your MSDN subscription and likely some with your enterprise agreement.